# Access Bone Coordinates using Python API

Tags: python, export, armature, bones

I'm trying to export bone coordinates using `ob.find_armature().data.bones`.

I made a test file that has two connected bones, and set these position values manually in the UI.

**Bone 1 Coordinates**

- Head: `(1, 1, 1)`
- Tail: `(2, 2, 2)`

**Bone 2 Coordinates** (connected to Bone 1)

- Head: `(2, 2, 2)`
- Tail: `(3, 3, 3)`

So I go to access the bone data in python, and here's what I get.

**Bone 1 Coordinates**

- Head: `(1, 1, 1)`
- Tail: `(2, 2, 2)`
- I guess these are absolute world coordinates.

**Bone 2 Coordinates** (connected to Bone 1)

- Head: `(0, 0, 0)` These must be relative to the last bone's tail.
- Tail: `(-0.00000, 1.732051, 0.000000)` **What are these?**

Proof and test Blend file: https://app.box.com/s/olb6hzi3p0z4ejqbtyfk

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM4Tc.png]

Comment: Figured out that `head_local` and `tail_local` will give me the coordinates I'm looking for, but I wish someone could explain what those other coordinates are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API docs:](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.head)

> **head** - Location of head end of the bone relative to its parent
>
> **head_local** - Location of head end of the bone relative to armature
>
> **tail** - Location of tail end of the bone
>
> **tail_local** - Location of tail end of the bone relative to armature

Since Bone 1 has no parent, the vector between object origin and bone head is used.

Bone 2's head it at Bone 1's tail (*Connected* is ticked), thus Bone 2's head is at `(0, 0, 0)` because there is no distance between both.

Bone 2's tail is at `(0, 1.732, 0)` because it's given relative to its parent bone. Bone 1 and 2 face the very same direction, all it takes is the length of the bone to define its endpoint (Bone direction is on the Y-axis in Blender). Tail minus head is

```
(3, 3, 3) - (2, 2, 2) = (1, 1, 1)
```

and the length

```
sqrt(12 + 12 + 12) = ~1.732
```

Comment: How would I go about calculating an absolute location based on that tail vector?

Comment: Should be `ob.matrix_world * bone.tail_local`. Not sure how to do that for `bone.tail`, likely involved some fancy matrix math.